# How do we programatically create a Project and Agent in Dialogflow?

Tags: spring-boot, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I am trying to automate the creation of Dialogflow agent and project from my Spring Boot Microservice application. The same is working very well on API explorer provided by google. But when I try the same from Postman to make a http call (which later I can do the same process inside the application) the authorization fails with insufficient permissions.

The same is possible with OAuth 2.0 integration from JavaScript layer. Here, the one using the UI will be layman and we don't want to expose Dialogflow logic to the end users and hence looking to do the same from microservice.

Is it possible to programatically create agents or that is not a feasible thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Dialogflow agents can be created programmatically:

Dialogflow v2 API provides methods which can be used to interact with Dialogflow agent programmatically.

- First you have to create a Google cloud project which can be done using API method as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project), make a note of the Project Id which will be used to call the Dialogflow API.
- Enable Dialogflow API in your Google Cloud project
- According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/setAgent?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22projects%2Fmy-agent-qqkb%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22displayName%22%3A%22Demo-Agent%22%7D%7D), projects.setAgent method is used to create or update the Dialogflow agent.
- You can try it on the API explorer by providing the required parameters

  agent.parent: projects/<project_id>

  request body:
  {
  "displayName": "<Agent_name>"
  }
- Enable the credentials and execute it. You will get a 200 success response and a new Agent will be created in the Dialogflow Console.

[image]

If you want to access Dialogflow from Postman:

- Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID
- From Postman, create a new Request and select the “Authorization” tab and choose Type "OAuth 2.0". Click 'Get New Access Token'
- send get/post request to the Dialogflow API
- For a detailed demo refer to this [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/blob/master/dialogflow-api-quick-start/postman/README.md) Link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include these things in the request header

```
 - grant_type = refresh_token
 - approval_prompt = force
 - redirect_uri
 - client_id
 - client_secret
 - prompt = consent
 - access_type = offline
 - refresh_token
```

By including these authorization will be successfull.